# Проблема с шаблонным аргументом-коллекцией (не конвертируется неявно в std::string)

Tags: c++

Пишу алгоритм на коллекциях, на вход в своих нуждах планирую подавать `std::vector` либо `std::string`, шаблонизировал тип входной коллекции:

```
template<T>
void Foo(const T &mas)
{
    int n = mas.size();
    // ...
}
```

Такой код не работает для следующего вызова:

```
Foo("abc");
```

Это логично, потому что шаблон выводит тип `const char[4]`, а не `std::string`. Что сделать, чтобы по-прежнему иметь возможность передачи в функцию вектора, но при этом чтобы при вышеуказанном вызове аргумент конвертировался в `std::string` ?

Я думал сделать специализацию шаблона для `std::string`, но вывод он сначала выводит тип аргумента и компиляция падает (вместо того, чтобы сначала взять специализацию, и попробовать сконвертировать аргумент).

Comment: Ой, не XY ли проблема у вас?... Но даже если нет - не морочьте голову, вызывайте `Foo("abc"s);` и не мучьтесь :)

Comment: Очень может быть что XY ) Моя функция обрабатывает строку, но этот алгоритм не специфичен для строк, и может работать на векторе, я зашаблонил вход (вместо того, чтобы написать там `std::string`), и получил описанное выше неудобство... А `"abc"s` что делает? Автоматическая конвертация в `string` ?

Comment: Добавление - что-то не сработало: `error: unable to find string literal operator 'operator""s' with 'const char [8]', 'unsigned int' arguments`... Компилировал с `-std=c++17`

Comment: С ошибкой разобрался, надо было добавить `using namespace std::string_literals;`

Comment: да, такой вариант есть, но может быть коду, использующую эту функцию, не нужно в других местах строковой литерал автоматически конвертировать в  std::string

Comment: А я сделал `using namespace std::string_literals;` только в блоке, в котором делаю такие вызовы. Это на самом деле кусочек юнит-тестов, там штук 10 подряд вызовов идут со строковыми литералами, я этот блок поместил в scope и там в начале поставил using...

Answer (score 4):

Можете добавить перегрузку:

```
inline auto Foo(const char * mas)
{
    return Foo<std::string>(mas);
}
```

Comment: Интересное решение, подожду других ответов, может ещё что посоветуют, но ваш вариант красив :)

Comment: Или даже `inline auto Foo(std::string const &mas) { return Foo<std::string>(mas); }`?

Comment: @bipll нет, для std::string перегрузка будет работать не так. В частности, код автора не соберется.

Comment: А, ну да, логично.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых  нет таково  `template<T>` синтаксиса... Нужно:

```
template<typename T> //или <class T>
void Foo(const T& mas)
{
    int n = mas.size();    
    // ...
}
```

В вашем случаи, код в шаблоне не будет работать для массивов и для всех других типов, которые не имеют функцию_член `size`. В общем случаи, если код функции меняется при работе с `С` строками, можно перегрузить другой шаблон:

```
template <std::size_t N>
void Foo(const char(&array)[N]) {
    int n = strlen(array);
    //...    
}
```

Если код функции не меняется, и вы хотите, чтобы при  вызове аргумент С_строка конвертировался в `std::string`, то можете вызвать функцию по первому шаблону:

```
template <std::size_t N>
void Foo(const char(&array)[N]) {
    Foo(std::string(array));
    //или
    Foo<std::string>(array);
}
//или же как в ответе от  Croessmah
```

Теперь можете вызывать функцию Foo("abc");

Answer (score 0):

Еще можно сделать `#include <iterator>`, а внутри `Foo` все вызовы `mas.size()`, `mas.begin()` etc. заменить на `std::size(mas)`, `std::begin(mas)`, etc.

Будет работать для строк, векторов, массивов, чего угодно.

Comment: Если передадут массив, то да, если же на вход подадут просто указатель на C-строку, то снова будет ошибка. Но это нужно у автора уточнить, нужна ли ему конвертация в string в таком случае.

Comment: C strings are evil. :-\

Comment: С-строки - наша жизнь )

Comment: Ну правда, какая в них надобность в плюсах в 2020 году?

Comment: ну, например, C-функции ничего не знают о std::string, а C-функции - это API операционной системы, сокеты, куча библиотек, свои переносимые библиотеки, и т.д. :) Да у того же std::string есть конструктор для строительства из C-строк. Так что работать с ними всё равно уметь надо.